# Using jQuery how to split text into span array

Tags: jquery

I want to split text to control it with html `<span>`

This my html code

```
<div class="siteLabel">Gallery/Technology/Music/Video/Business/Nature/People/Sports/Car/Fashion/Learn/Typography</div>
```

the result should be like this

```
<div class="siteLabel">
  <span>Gallery</span>
  <span>Technology</span>
  <span>Music</span>
  <span>Video</span>
  <span>Business</span>
  <span>Nature</span>
  <span>People</span>
  <span>Sports</span>
  <span>Car</span>
  <span>Fashion</span>
  <span>Learn</span>
  <span>Typography</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that the labels number not static it may be more or less, so i can't use something like `.split('/')`

Comment: why can't you use `.split('/')`?

Comment: using `.split('/')` require select every label by it's number Gallery [0] , Technology [1] and so on. but this text of labels not static it may changed so i can't select it using numbers.

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = $(".siteLabel").text().split("/");
var html="";
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    html+= "<span>"+arr[i]+"</span>";
}
$(".siteLabel").html(html);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6r8owpay/)**

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be to still use `.split('/')`.  Here is how you could do it using plain JavaScript:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.siteLabel');
var text = el.textContent ? el.textContent : el.innerText;
var items = text.split('/');
var html = '';

items.forEach(function(text){  
  html += '<span>'+text+'</span>';
});

el.innerHTML = html;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e97e4Lsd/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex like

```js
$('.siteLabel').html(function(i, html) {
  return html.trim().replace(/(.+?)(\/|$)/g, '<span>$1</span>')
})
```

```css
.siteLabel span {
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="siteLabel">Gallery/Technology/Music/Video/Business/Nature/People/Sports/Car/Fashion/Learn/Typography</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun it's helpful but a small thing it gives one empty `<span></span>` at the end of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".siteLabel").html(function(_, words) {
  return words.match(/[^\/]\w+/g).map(function(word) {
           return $("<span>", {"html": word}).add("<br />")
         });
})
```

```js
$(".siteLabel").html(function(_, words) {
  return words.match(/[^\/]\w+/g)
            .map(function(word) {
              return $("<span>", {"html": word}).add("<br />")
            });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="siteLabel">Gallery/Technology/Music/Video/Business/Nature/People/Sports/Car/Fashion/Learn/Typography</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = $('.siteLabel').text().split('/');
    debugger;
$('.siteLabel').empty();
$.each(items, function(index, item){
    debugger;
    $('.siteLabel').append("<span>" + item)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```